# Why header show blue color using material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

Could you please tell me Why header show blue color ? I already try to change theme colour but  it not work .I am expecting “Red” color

using from this link
https://material-ui.com/demos/app-bar/
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/7191w73nxx

```
 <div className="App">
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={theme}>
          <AppBar position="static" color="primary" className="app-header">
            <Toolbar>
              <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit">
                Photos
              </Typography>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `<MuiThemeProvider>`, you are passing the prop `muiTheme={theme}`. This is incorrect. You should be using prop `theme`, like so:

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
```

Your code sandbox, after a quick edit to the prop name, looked like this:
[image]

The [Material-UI Themes documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#palette) shows some helpful examples, where you can view the source code to see how to use them in your React app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code. https://codesandbox.io/s/w0xrmpy1m8

Only mistake was  `<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>`
expected `theme` for props instead of 
`muiTheme` which you had provided